# Red Gate - .NET Reflector Visual Studio Extension Version 10 - Visual Studio 2017 - Need to Disable Obfuscation

Tags: obfuscation, visual-studio-extensions, deobfuscation, redgate, .net-reflector

I recently installed this extension. It is letting me step into the source code of dlls the source of which I own. Unfortunately I see the code I am stepping into has been obfuscated.

**I have not been able to find a way to disable this obfuscation.** I need to be able to do this in order to understand what I am actually debugging, set watch variables correctly, etc. **How can I go about doing disabling this obfuscation?**

Comment: Do you have the .pdb files?

Comment: I definitely do